# Kivy Popup rendering issue

Tags: python, popup, kivy, render

I'm working on a bus driver app. Once in a while, there are messages published on a MQTT topic which the app is subscribed to (by a server). When such message comes, a popup must appear. I customized the default Kivy popup: changed the background, added as the content a FloatLayout with a Lable and a Button.

The problem is that once in several cases (5-6) the texture elements of the popup jumps away, like the background, or the Label text, or the button's image.

Here is the Kivy definition of my Popup class:

```
<BktsPopup@Popup>:
title: 'Alert message'
title_align: 'center'
title_size: 25
size_hint: (0.6, 0.6)
# size: (400, 300)
auto_dismiss: False
separator_height: 0
message: popup_msg
border: (14, 14, 14, 14)

FloatLayout:
    BktsLabel:
        id: popup_msg
        font_size: 20
        size_hint_y: 0.7
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}
        # size_hint_y: 60
    BktsButton:
        id: ok_btn
        background_normal: 'res/btn_released_gray.png'
        background_down: 'res/btn_pressed_gray.png'        
        size_hint_x: 0.4
        size_hint_y: 0.3
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}
        text: 'OK'
        font_size: 25
        on_press: root.dismiss()
```

Here is the python class:

```
class BktsPopup(Popup):
    popup_back_color = ListProperty([])
    message = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, text, title, level):
        Popup.__init__(self)
        self.title = title
        self.message.text = text
        if level is LEVEL_NORMAL:
            self.background = 'res/popup_back_green.png'
        elif level is LEVEL_URGENT:
            self.background = 'res/popup_back_red.png'
```

Here's how the popup is being opened:

```
def on_dispatcher_message(self, level, text):
    popup = BktsPopup(text, 'Dispatcher', level)
    popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.send_message_ack)
    popup.open()
    self.store_event(text)
```

Here's the normal appearance of the popup:
[image: normal case]

Here's a texture-anomaly case:
[image: bad case]

Sometimes, the whole background jumps and appears in the left-bottom corner.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Which python and kivy version do you use? Do you use threads anywhere in the app?

Comment: python 2.7, Kivy 1.9.0, no threads

Comment: Try using kivy 1.9.1 or even 1.9.2-dev, maybe it could solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide an example with which answerer doesn't need to reinvent all your custom classes/rules. Anyway, does it happen if you use some other kivy-only image instead the default one? Kivy images you can access via [`atlas`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.atlas.html).

Comment: @MariusAdauge I know this is an old post, but did you happen to fix it?