# kivy Popup fails under Windows 10

Tags: python, multithreading, popup, kivy

This is similar to a question asked about an earlier version of Kivy: [Kivy Popup rendering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183393/kivy-popup-rendering-issue)
But no useful answer was found.

This is a simplified version of a problem I am having with Popup under Windows 10 with Kivy 1.9.1 and Python 2.7.12. The problem doesn't appear every time the Popup is opened, but it happens about 50% of the time. The symptoms are that the layout of the Popup is sometimes incorrect and sometimes drastically incorrect (i.e., button text not even on the button, or the title not even inside the Popup). I am using a Thread and a Queue to wait for the Popup to finish. To see the problem, run the kivyplay.py script, click on "Start Game Thread", The click on the "OK" button in the Popup. The Popup will appear 4 times, and if the problem doesn't appear, you can click on "Start Game Thread" again. The warning message I see is:

```
[WARNING           ] <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0x000000000ADDF118> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
```

I am not directly using any GridLayout widgets. This same code works flawlessly and without warnings under Ubuntu 16.04 with the same versions of Kivy and Python.

I have tried numerous different approaches:

- Using threading locks instead of a Queue
- Creating a Popup in MyPopup rather than subclassing
- Creating a ModalView in MyPopup rather than subclassing
- Eliminate the pop_test.kv completely and just use a Button as the Popup content

Using a ModalView eliminates the GridLayout warnings, but doesn't fix the problem. It seems that the more complex the popup layout is, the more often the error appears, so this simple example doesn't show the error quite as often. Am I doing something wrong? Any ideas on how to get the popups to render correctly? Should I report this as a bug?

Thanks!!!

kivyplay.kv:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

from game_thread import GameThread

class KivyPlay(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        RelativeLayout.__init__(self, *args)

    def start_thread(self):
        print "Got a click"
        gameThread = GameThread()
        gameThread.start()

    def quit(self):
        app.stop()

class PlayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KivyPlay()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PlayApp()
    app.run()
```

game_thread.py:

```
from threading import *
from Queue import Queue

from my_popup import MyPopup

class GameThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self, name="GameThread")
        self.daemon = True
        self.queue = Queue()


    def run(self):

        for i in range(0,4):
            popup = MyPopup("Popup Test", self.queue, i)
            popup.open()
            popReturn = self.queue.get(True)
            print "Popup #" + str(i) + " returned " + str(popReturn)
```

my_popup.ky:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyPopup(Popup):

    def __init__(self, theTitle, theQueue, playerNumber):
        self.queue = theQueue
        title = theTitle
        self.player = playerNumber
        myContent = Builder.load_file('pop_test.kv')
        self.button = myContent.ids["ok_button"]
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.okButton)
        Popup.__init__(self, title=title, title_align='center', content=myContent, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400,150), auto_dismiss=False)

    def okButton(self, *args):
        self.queue.put(self.player, False)
        self.dismiss()
```

play.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<KivyPlay>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}
        text: 'Start Game Thread'
        on_press: root.start_thread()

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.25}
        text: 'Quit'
        on_press: root.quit()
```

pop_test.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Button:
            id: ok_button
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            text: 'OK'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the point of your comment? I followed the guide in your link when I created this question. It IS complete, minimal and verifiable.

Comment: The point is,you dont need 4 files to make a minimal example of your popup. There is alot of irrelevant stuff implemented in the code, like thread and queue. You only need a simple Popup to reproduce your error.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I know this is an old post, but did you find a fix?

Comment: I finally determined that the problem was that I was doing GUI operations on a thread other than the main thread, as well as the error pointed out in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super()` at the top, when running `__init__`, to be sure you initiate the widget, before you begin overiding stuff in the class.

So I changed three of your files. And I dont see any error (tested on win 10). You can ignore the gridlayout warning.

kivy_play.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

from game_thread import GameThread

class KivyPlay(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyPlay,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def start_thread(self):
        print "Got a click"
        gameThread = GameThread()
        gameThread.start()

    def quit(self):
        app.stop()

class PlayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KivyPlay()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PlayApp()
    app.run()
```

And my_popup.py:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('pop_test.kv')

class MyPopup(Popup):

    def __init__(self, theTitle, theQueue, playerNumber,**kwargs):
        super(MyPopup,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = theTitle
        self.title_align='center'
        self.queue = theQueue
        self.player = playerNumber
        self.size_hint=(None, None)
        self.size=(400,150)
        self.auto_dismiss=False


    def okButton(self, *args):
        self.queue.put(self.player, False)
        self.dismiss()
```

pop_test.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<MyPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            Button:
                id: ok_button
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                text: 'OK'
                on_press:root.okButton()
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but it didn't fix the problem. I still see the bad layout occasionally.  Perhaps my initial estimate of 50% occurrence was a bit high, but I see it often enough that I would not provide my code to a customer who intends to run it on Windows 10. I also tried using the developmental version of kivy (v1.9.2-dev0), but it made no difference.

Comment: @JohnAnderson ok, I will try to run it multiple times. Maybe I spot something.

Comment: I decided to capture images of the incorrectly rendered popups. That was also failing trying to use Widget.export_to_png() or Window.screenshot(). So I ended up using a subprocess to get the images. The code is a bit different than above, but here is the expected result: ![correct](https://www.dropbox.com/s/na0ljxgaxi6a4g6/correct..png?dl=0) and here is a typical error: ![error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3vgunke8mdkptw/error2.png?dl=0)  Not sure if I did these image links correctly. I am suspecting that the problem may concern the NVIDIA driver.